# "Antecedent" vs. "predecessor"

Tags: word-choice, differences

When do I use the word *antecedent* and when should I prefer *predecessor*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "antecedent" will - with the -ent suffix - tend to be less material, and more abstract.  Thus, an antecedent tends to be an idea or concept that preceded the current mental/juridical/linguistic environment.

A "predecessor" will - by virtue of the -or suffix -- tend to be more material, and objective.   Thus, a predecessor tends to be a worldly person or thing that came before in time.

A person can be my genetic predecessor, but they can not be my genetic antecedent;   a person's character, or accomplishments, however, can serve as a historical antecedent to my own accomplishments or achievements, and therefore that person can be said to be my own "antecedent".

Answer (score 3):

Unless otherwise specified (or ruled out by context), *predecessor* tends to refer to the thing immediately before the one you're talking about, while *antecedent* just means something that preceded it some time earlier, but was not necessarily immediately before.

Answer (score 2):

*Antecedent* can also mean events that happened before - it doesn't necessarily mean ancestors.

*Predecessor* generally refers to a person or an object.